# Регулярное выражение. Парсинг HTML

Tags: регулярные-выражения, jsoup

Есть элементы Jsoup:

```
a class="bloko-link" data-qa="vacancy-serp__vacancy-title" target="_blank" href="https://hh.ru/vacancy/47676640?from=vacancy_search_list&query=java%20Moscow"

a class="bloko-link" target="_blank" href="https://feedback.hh.ru/article/details/id/5951"
```

Разница первого со вторым **data-qa**.
Мне нужно получить второй элемент.
Как составить регулярное выражение в select() исключающее первый элемент?
P.S. Задача вытащить вторую ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярки сравнивают строку с шаблоном, а не строку со строкой.

Посему, нужно из первой и второй строк сотворить шаблоны, а потом сравнивать первую строку с шаблоном, созданным из второй строки и вторую строку с шаблоном, который сотворили из первой.

Очевидно, что это изврат. Более продуктивно разбить на массивы по пробелу и исключить из 1-го массивы элементы 2-го и наоборот. Или исключать подстроки из строк, если нет возможности работать с массивами/списками. По итогу останется в первом то, чего нету во втором, во втором то, чего нету в первом. Ну а там уже по обстоятельствам.

Если есть возможность работать с данными, как с dom-элементами, то можно напрямую атрибуты/свойства сравнивать.